# Showing Data (as Object) in a TextBox?

Tags: vb.net

The code I use:

> Dim enc As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
>
> TextBox.Text = enc.GetString(datas)

**datas**'s type is Object, and its value comes from a .dll file that contains some data, such as "The web page address is www......"

But that code doesn't show all the data in the textbox, only the first letter (T) appears. What do I do?

Comment: Show the code that retrieves your data. Make sure you're not just loading the first character into your object.

Answer (score 0):

Override the object's ToString method and pass that.

TextBox.Text = object.tostring.

The easiest thing to do is just make a

```
Partial Class ObjectClass
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
       Return Me.WhateverPropOrFieldYouWantToReturn
    End Function
End Class
```

I hope this answer iscorrect AND helps = true :):)